Sending an email using Indy10 and OpenSSL is throwing error: "Transaction failed Reject due to policy restrictions"
I am using Delphi 10.4.3, Indy 10.6.2.0, and OpenSSL DLL versions 1.0.2u. My program sends an email at process completion, but in the last few months it's been throwing an error when attempting to send the email.
So I threw together this small test program to help solve the issue:
procedure TForm2.btn_SendMailClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Set parameters
  IdSMTP1.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandler;
  IdSMTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  IdSSLIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  try
    // Connect to server using port 587
    IdSMTP1.Connect;
      try
        // Send the message
        IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1);
        //if an exception occurs…
        except on E : Exception do
           begin
              ShowMessage('An error occurred: ' + E.Message + sLineBreak +
                  'Exception Class: ' + E.ClassName + sLineBreak +
                  'Help Context: ' + IntToStr(E.HelpContext));
           end;
        end;
  finally
    begin
      IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
    end;
  end;
end;

The server is a hosted server at Ionos, and my hunch is that a policy change might be causing this. The program above does connect to the server, but I get this error message on the IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage1); command.
The error is:
Exception class EIdSMTPReplyError with message
'Transaction failed
Reject due to policy restrictions.
For explanation visit https://www.ionos.com/help/index.php?id=2425&ip=73.226.186.52&c=hd&r=1MGRBx-1stE1m26c1-00DPsU
'.

When I looked up the error on their site I get:

554 Transaction failed, reject due to policy restrictions
Problem:
The email was rejected by the IONOS SMTP server because the standards defined in RFC 5321 and RFC 5322 were not adhered to.
Solution:
The email client must meet the following criteria:

The header lines of the email must contain exactly one valid "Date" line according to RFC 2822.

The following header lines may only exist once: From, Sender, To, CC, Subject

The header lines mentioned must be syntactically correct


Note: The To and CC lines can contain multiple recipients.
In accordance with the recommendations from RFC7103, incorrect messages are not automatically corrected by IONOS, otherwise DKIM signatures become invalid. For more information about DKIM signatures, see the IONOS article Configuring DMARC Records for a Domain.

I have followed the recommendations outlined in the Solution section above, and have a message into support at IONOS inquiring about any recent (last few months) policy changes, but what other options might you suggest or places to look to resolve this issue?

"I am using ... Indy 10.6.2.0" - the current version is 10.6.3.4, you might consider upgrading. In any case, Indy conforms to the restrictions mentioned on the IONOS site (you can verify that for yourself by looking at the data that TIdMessage generates, either by using TIdMessage.SaveToFile(), or by assigning an intercept component to TIdSMTP.Intercept such as TIdLogFile). So, I think you will have to wait for a reply from IONOS to find out what specific policy is being violated before you can do anything to fix it.

Thanks Remy. The logging commands helped, as the IdMessage1.From.Address was blank.
